# Can UIWebView be used to view and edit XML documents in an iOS app

Tags: ios, xml, ipad, uiwebview, uidocument

If my app creates and edits outline-style XML documents, can the documents be rendered in a UIWebView and edited, while rendered, in that same view?

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript-based XML editor might work inside a UIWebView. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378205/web-xml-editor-with-xml-syntax-highlighting for a list.